# Variable after redirect PHP

Tags: php, redirect, web

Is there a way to carry over a variable after a redirect ?

For example on a projects.php

```
foreach ($projects as $key=>$project) : ?>
    <li class="">
        <a href="<?= root_url('project/'.$project->url_title) ?>/" title="<?= $project->name ?>">
            <? if ( isset($project->images[0]) ) :
                $thumb_image_path = $project->images[0]->getThumbnailPath(310, 276, true, array('mode'=>'fit'));
            else :
                $thumb_image_path = '//placehold.it/320x285/ffffff/000000';
            endif ?>
            <? // echo $thumb_image_path; ?> 
            <img src="<?= $thumb_image_path ?>" alt="<?= $project->name ?>">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4><?= $project->name ?></h4>
                <h5 class="hide-for-small-only">Not dynamic</h5>
                <p class="hide-for-small-only"><?= $project->description ?></p>
            </div> 
        </a>
    </li>
<? endforeach ?>
```

When redirected to project/nameoftheproject , is there a way to still have access to the variable $project ? So I could use it to do $project->title

Thanks for your answers

Comment: stuff it into a session, or send it over via cookie or query string.

Comment: Session or cookie would be the best option. Compressing an object into a query string would be messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @MarcB, you can add the variable to a query string:

`your_url?variable=foo`

Or add it to a session

`$_SESSION['variable'] = 'foo';`

or a cookie (mmmm)

`$_COOKIE['variable'] = 'foo';
setcookie('variable', 'foo');`